# How to add up with a variable instead a number in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, variables, addition

Hi guys i am trying to select a the 2nd value and then add this value to the rest of the array exept the 1st value.

this is what i have so far. 
Xloc = X.iloc(1) # selecting the second variable
X = X[1:-1] + Xloc # this doenst work but if i do + 1.25 it works...

the Dataframe

```
X

0

1.25

2.57

4.5

6.9

7.3
```

Expected Result

```
X

0

2.5

3.82

5.75

8.15

8.55
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this is your original df

```
   N
0  0.00
1  1.25
2  2.57
3  4.50
4  6.90
5  7.30
```

you can assign these values and use a simple concat to add in the original value in place

```
df['M'] = pd.concat([df["N"].iloc[:1], (df["N"].iloc[1:] + df["N"].iloc[1])])

print(df)

      N     M
0  0.00  0.00
1  1.25  2.50
2  2.57  3.82
3  4.50  5.75
4  6.90  8.15
5  7.30  8.55
```